# How do “Ripstiks” work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life

I have no clue how Ripstiks work, people wiggle the sections of it without ever having to touch the ground after starting, and some how move keep moving forward. I know how to use a Ripstik, but my question is: *where is the propelling force on a Ripstik coming from?*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caster_board#Movement